# C# Winform: Inline datagridview edit

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

initially my `datagridview` would look like below

```
ID      Name        City        Action
------  ------      ----        ------
1       Mitch       Kolkata     Edit
2       Simon       Delhi       Edit
3       Poly        Madras      Edit
```

all data will be in read only format. so user can not change but when user click on edit button then a textbox will be placed in name column and a city `dropdown` will be placed on city column on a row whose edit button will be clicked by user.

when user click on edit button then edit button text will be change to Save and when user click on Save button then save button text will be change to Edit. so guide me how to achieve in line edit functionality when working with `datagridview`. thanks

Comment: do yourself a quick google search on how to `Update DataGridView using ItemTemplate` you would want to have an edit button as part of the grid.. there are tons of working examples on how to do this.. please show more effort on your part ...you state that `initially my datagridview would look like` meaning that you didn't do anything yet..? can you show us what you have tried on your own thus far..

Comment: i am working DataGridView in C# winform template. i guess there is no ItemTemplate like concept. ItemTemplate  is in gridview in asp.net webform.

Answer (score 5):

What you are asking for is not naturally supported by the `DataGridView`, so you need to implement the whole logic by maintaining some state, hooking into several events and setting several properties.

The essential part is setting the appropriate column/cell properties.

(A) Initial setup

```
var colName = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { HeaderText = "Name" };
var colCity = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn { HeaderText = "City" };
var colAction = new DataGridViewButtonColumn { HeaderText = "Action" };
colName.ReadOnly = true;
colCity.ReadOnly = true;
colCity.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing;
colAction.Text = "Edit";
```

(B) Enter edit mode

```
var cellName = (DataGridViewTextBoxCell)row.Cells[colName.Index];
var cellCity = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)row.Cells[colCity.Index];
var cellAction = (DataGridViewButtonCell)row.Cells[colAction.Index];
cellName.ReadOnly = false;
cellCity.ReadOnly = false;
cellCity.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.ComboBox;
dg.CurrentCell = cellName;
dg.BeginEdit(true);
cellAction.Value = "Save";
```

(C) Exit edit mode

```
var cellName = (DataGridViewTextBoxCell)row.Cells[colName.Index];
var cellCity = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)row.Cells[colCity.Index];
var cellAction = (DataGridViewButtonCell)row.Cells[colAction.Index];
cellName.ReadOnly = true;
cellCity.ReadOnly = true;
cellCity.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing;
cellAction.Value = "Edit";
```

Here is a fully working demo:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Demos
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            var form = new Form();
            var dg = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Parent = form };
            dg.AllowUserToAddRows = dg.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
            var colId = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { HeaderText = "Id", ReadOnly = true };
            var colName = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { HeaderText = "Name" };
            var colCity = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn { HeaderText = "City" };
            var colAction = new DataGridViewButtonColumn { HeaderText = "Action" };
            colName.ReadOnly = true;
            colCity.ReadOnly = true;
            colCity.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing;
            colAction.Text = "Edit";
            dg.Columns.AddRange(colId, colName, colCity, colAction);
            var data = new[]
            {
                new { Id = 1, Name = "Mitch", City = "Kolkata" },
                new { Id = 2, Name = "Simon", City = "Delhi" },
                new { Id = 3, Name = "Poly", City = "Madras" },
            };
            colCity.Items.AddRange(data.Select(item => item.City).Distinct().ToArray());
            foreach (var item in data)
                dg.Rows.Add(item.Id, item.Name, item.City, "Edit");
            Action<DataGridViewRow> enterEditMode = row =>
            {
                var cellName = (DataGridViewTextBoxCell)row.Cells[colName.Index];
                var cellCity = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)row.Cells[colCity.Index];
                var cellAction = (DataGridViewButtonCell)row.Cells[colAction.Index];
                cellName.ReadOnly = false;
                cellCity.ReadOnly = false;
                cellCity.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.ComboBox;
                dg.CurrentCell = cellName;
                dg.BeginEdit(true);
                cellAction.Value = "Save";
            };
            Action<DataGridViewRow> exitEditMode = row =>
            {
                var cellName = (DataGridViewTextBoxCell)row.Cells[colName.Index];
                var cellCity = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)row.Cells[colCity.Index];
                var cellAction = (DataGridViewButtonCell)row.Cells[colAction.Index];
                cellName.ReadOnly = true;
                cellCity.ReadOnly = true;
                cellCity.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing;
                cellAction.Value = "Edit";
            };
            dg.CellContentClick += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (e.ColumnIndex == colAction.Index)
                {
                    var row = dg.Rows[e.RowIndex];
                    var cellAction = (DataGridViewButtonCell)row.Cells[colAction.Index];
                    if ((string)cellAction.Value == "Edit")
                        enterEditMode(row);
                    else if (dg.EndEdit())
                    {
                        // Save code goes here ...
                        exitEditMode(row);
                    }
                }
            };
            dg.RowValidated += (sender, e) =>
            {
                var row = dg.Rows[e.RowIndex];
                var cellAction = (DataGridViewButtonCell)row.Cells[colAction.Index];
                if ((string)cellAction.Value == "Save")
                    exitEditMode(row);
            };
            Application.Run(form);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [EditMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editmode(v=vs.110).aspx) on the Grid to [EditOnEnter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridvieweditmode(v=vs.110).aspx) so that the cell is put in edit mode when it is clicked.

You will still have to handle your save function externally of the DataGridView.

Comment: i do not want to put all rows in edit mode rather i want to edit a row where user click on edit button. so how programmatically set a specific row in edit mode ? is it possible. would u mind to give some sample code.

Comment: then write the code that gets the currently selected row from within the button click ...show us what code you have written or tried on your own

Comment: @Mou Please show me what you have so far and I can help you refactor it for what you need.